# Have well-defined, narrowly-focused classes ... now how do I get anything done in my program?

Tags: python, oop

I'm coding a poker hand evaluator as my first programming project. I've made it through three classes, each of which accomplishes its narrowly-defined task very well:

HandRange = a string-like object (e.g. "AA"). getHands() returns a list of tuples for each specific hand within the string:

```
[(Ad,Ac),(Ad,Ah),(Ad,As),(Ac,Ah),(Ac,As),(Ah,As)]
```

Translation = a dictionary that maps the return list from getHands to values that are useful for a given evaluator (yes, this can probably be refactored into another class).

```
{'As':52, 'Ad':51, ...}
```

Evaluator = takes a list from HandRange (as translated by Translator), enumerates all possible hand matchups and provides win % for each.

My question: what should my "domain" class for using all these classes look like, given that I may want to connect to it via either a shell UI or a GUI? Right now, it looks like an assembly line process:

```
user_input = HandRange()
x = Translation.translateList(user_input)
y = Evaluator.getEquities(x)
```

This smells funny in that it feels like it's procedural when I ought to be using OO.

In a more general way: if I've spent so much time ensuring that my classes are well defined, narrowly focused, orthogonal, whatever ... how do I actually manage work flow in my program when I need to use all of them in a row?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: "This smells funny in that it feels like it's procedural when I ought to be using OO."  Isn't the algorithm inherently procedural?  What's the actual problem with it?  OO programming is wrapped around core procedural programming.  How else could this be specified?  Do you have an alternative procedure that is less "procedural"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make a fetish of object orientation -- Python supports multiple paradigms, after all!  Think of your user-defined types, AKA classes, as building blocks that gradually give you a "language" that's closer to your domain rather than to general purpose language / library primitives.

At some point you'll want to code "verbs" (actions) that use your building blocks to *perform* something (under command from whatever interface you'll supply -- command line, RPC, web, GUI, ...) -- and those may be module-level functions as well as methods within some encompassing class.  You'll surely want a class if you need multiple instances, and most likely also if the actions involve updating "state" (instance variables of a class being much nicer than globals) or if inheritance and/or polomorphism come into play; but, there is no a priori reason to prefer classes to functions otherwise.

If you find yourself writing static methods, yearning for a singleton (or Borg) design pattern, writing a class with no state (just methods) -- these are all "code smells" that should prompt you to check whether you really need a class for that subset of your code, or rather whether you may be overcomplicating things and should use a module with functions for that part of your code.  (Sometimes after due consideration you'll unearth some different reason for preferring a class, and that's allright too, but the point is, don't just pick a class over a module w/functions "by reflex", without critically thinking about it!).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Poker class that ties these all together and intialize all of that stuff in the `__init__()` method:

```
class Poker(object):
    def __init__(self, user_input=HandRange()):
        self.user_input = user_input
        self.translation = Translation.translateList(user_input)
        self.evaluator = Evaluator.getEquities(x)

    # and so on...

p = Poker()
# etc, etc...
```